# How does transactionScope effect Azure Queue?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

If an Azure Queue transaction (push/pop) is made inside of a transactionScope, do they need to be committed or are they done regardless of transaction completeness?

Comment: Are you using Service Bus queues or Azure Storage queues?

Comment: Azure Storage Queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage Queues [do not support transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted), so the change is immediate.

Comment: That definitely answers my question. Thanks a bunch.